# visualize the embedding $\mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb{C}) \supset \mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{C}) \supset \mathrm{SU}(2)$ in a larger $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?

Tags: differential-geometry, representation-theory, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, spin-geometry

1. How to visualize the following embedding:
   $$
   \mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb{C}) \supset \mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{C}) \supset \mathrm{SU}(2). \tag{1}
   $$
   They are all Lie groups thus manifolds.
   By this "visualize the following embedding", I meant that

- the $\mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ is a non-compact 8-dimensional (real) manifold.
- the $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ is a non-compact 6-dimensional (real) manifold.
- the $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ is a  compact 3-dimensional (real) manifold which is a 3-sphere $S^3$.

Since it is fairly easy to visualize $S^3$, which is a unit sphere on a $\mathbb{R}^4$; then we may start from $S^3$ and go to consider the embedding
$$
 S^3= \mathrm{SU}(2) \subset \mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})  \subset  \mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb{C}) . \tag{2}
$$

2. Could we put everything in (1) and (2) into a flat Euclidean space with sufficient large dimension? Say in $\mathbb{R}^{8}$ or $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?

Comment: $\mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ is an open subset of $M_{2}(\mathbb{C})=\mathbb{C}^{2\times 2}\cong \mathbb{R}^{8}$, This means that each of these Lie groups is a properly embedded submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^8$ under this identification.

Comment: great + 1, how to visualize the subset GL(2,ℂ)  in ℝ^8? Also how about the other embedding into this ℝ^8?  GL(2,ℂ)⊃SL(2,ℂ)⊃SU(2) in a larger ℝ^8? many thanks!

Comment: A monor nitpick at @J.V.Gaiter 's comment: the embedding $GL(2,\mathbb{C})\to\mathbb{R}^8$ is not proper.

Comment: Also I feel that the 4 complex matrix elements of the rank-2 matrix of GL(2,ℂ) seem not have any constraint. So it seems that I can cover the full ℝ^8 by the 4 complex matrix elements. So why GL(2,ℂ) is an open or not an open subset of 2(ℂ)=ℂ2×2≅ℝ8? It looks to be the full cover

Comment: @МаринаMarinaS Elements of $GL(2,\mathbb{C})$ must have nonzero determinant.

Comment: @Kajelad, good point, because we need to have an inverse group element to define a GROUP!

Comment: It sort of depends what you mean by _visualize_, but the set of $2\times2$ matrices of determinant $0$ is a complex cone that (after we remove the zero matrix) maps to a complex quadric in three-dimensional projective space under projection $\mathbf{C}^{2\times2}\simeq\mathbf{C}^4\to\mathbf{CP}^3$. (Analogously, $GL(2,\mathbf{R})$ is the complement of a cone on a Clifford torus.)

Comment: @Andrew D. Hwang, yes along this line, we get a good picture --  could you write an answer on this?